# How do I stop Emacs micro-stuttering and high CPU utilization caused by background calls to git?

Tags: git, performance, version-control, crash

Using Emacs on Windows, I experiences issues due to background invocations of `git.exe`. The same issues might apply on Linux, though the more light-weight process calling might make them unnoticable.

### Symptoms

- Occassionally, Windows will report that "Git has crashed", regardless of active Desktop window.
- In the Task Manager, one to two `git.exe` processes appear every few seconds and vanish again.
- In Emacs, random micro-stutters occur.

### Diagnosis Attempts

- Using “Process Explorer” (procexp.exe), it can be found that the `git.exe` processes are subprocesses of Emacs.
- They occur whenever a file inside a git-versioned directory is opened. 
  More such directories → more stuttering.
- Doing `M-x trace-function RET call-process RET` with four files opened across two git repositories shows upwards of 30 git invocations per cycle. A high number of *synchronous* calls definitely explains stuttering.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

The problems turned out to be caused by the customization variable `auto-revert-check-vc-info`.

If this setting is active, the version control software – git in my case – will be invoked every `auto-revert-interval` seconds (default 5) for *each* repository, causing the described behavior.

The only solutions I found were to increase the interval (counter-productive) and to disable `auto-revert-check-vc-info` (acceptable for me).